# Implementing an N-dimensional Matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading, n-dimensional

I want to implement my own N-dimensional Matrix class in C++. I am, however, stuck as to how I would go about implementing it, especially when it comes to implementing the operators to access an element in that matrix.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use an existing library or you'll regret it.

Comment: @iavr The problem is, my code should be portable and should not rely on non-standard libraries like Boost. So unless C++ has a standard way of doing this, I'm afraid I'll need to implement it from scratch.

Comment: Is it a sparse matrix?

Comment: @EdHeal No not necessarily. In any case, the size of any dimension would probably not exceed 10, so the matrix should be small in general.

Comment: 10^n can be a rather large number

Comment: @EdHeal True. I should have also mentioned that n will likely never exceed 5.

Comment: @alguru - How much data in each cell? How many cells will contain data?

Comment: @EdHeal Cells will be of type `double` and probably all cells will contain data.

Comment: @alguru - that us the 6th dimension

Comment: @EdHeal That would be n^10; and yes, this grows fast (not as fast as 10^n though ;) ), but that's not a problem of implementation, people should know what they're asking to allocate before they do

Comment: Check [marray](https://github.com/dimatura/marray). It's a good compromise between a full-fledged library like those of Boost and something you would make on your own. It will make you appreciate the difficulties and if you don't like the license, at least it will give you ideas.

Comment: @alguru Plus, keep in mind that whatever you implement yourself is non-standard as well. So, do you trust yourself more?

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a very simple version that's been tested for months now so I think it's quite reliable: https://github.com/Sheljohn/ndArray

It is entirely standard C++11-based (use `-std=c++0x` when compiling with g++); no external dependency, and should be platform-independent (not tested). It does offer compatibility with Matlab though, but you can easily remove the parts that are specific to `mxArray`s. Let me know if you chose to use it and want to extend it; the current version is intended to offer the bare minimum, but I'm happy to help for any extension/bug.

---

There you go, this should compile just fine. The documentation is in the comments or on Github.

`ndArray.h`

```
#ifndef __ND_ARRAY__
#define __ND_ARRAY__

//================================================
// @file         ndArray.h
// @author       Jonathan Hadida
// @contact      cf https://github.com/Sheljohn/MexArray
//================================================

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdio>

#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <initializer_list>

// Protect 1D access (comment for faster access)
#define ND_ARRAY_SAFE_ACCESS
#ifdef ND_ARRAY_SAFE_ACCESS
#define ND_ARRAY_PROTECT(k,n) (k % n)
#else
#define ND_ARRAY_PROTECT(k,n) k
#endif



        /********************     **********     ********************/
        /********************     **********     ********************/



/**
 * Convert nd coordinates to 1d index.
 * Two main variants are provided:
 * - Taking an ARRAY as coordinates (size input by template)
 * - Taking a VA_LIST as a list of coordinate inputs (cf operator() below).
 */
template <unsigned N>
unsigned sub2ind( const unsigned *subs, const unsigned *size, const unsigned *strides )
{
    register unsigned ind = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
        ind += ND_ARRAY_PROTECT(subs[i],size[i]) * strides[i];

    return ind;
}

template <unsigned N>
unsigned sub2ind( va_list& vl, const unsigned *size, const unsigned *strides )
{
    register unsigned ind = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 1; i < N; ++i) 
        ind += ND_ARRAY_PROTECT(va_arg(vl,unsigned),size[i]) * strides[i];

    va_end(vl); return ind;
}

template <> inline unsigned 
sub2ind<0>( const unsigned*, const unsigned*, const unsigned* )
    { return 0; }
template <> inline unsigned 
sub2ind<1>( const unsigned *subs, const unsigned*, const unsigned* )
    { return *subs; }
template <> inline unsigned 
sub2ind<2>( const unsigned *subs, const unsigned *size, const unsigned* )
    { return (subs[0] + subs[1]*size[0]); }

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Simple singleton.
 */
template <typename T> struct singleton { static T instance; };
template <typename T> T singleton<T>::instance = T();

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Dummy deleter functor.
 * This litterally does nothing to the input pointer; it can be used 
 * safely with shared pointers for either statically allocated memory 
 * (eg fixed-size arrays) or externally managed memory (eg Matlab in/out).
 */
template <typename T>
struct no_delete
{ inline void operator() ( T* ptr ) const {} };



        /********************     **********     ********************/
        /********************     **********     ********************/



/**
 * n-dimensional array.
 * NOTE: T can be CONST (underlying elements non-assignable), 
 * or NON-CONST (underlying elements assignable, suitable for 
 * owned memory allocation for instance).
 */
template <typename T, unsigned N>
class ndArray
{
public:

    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef T& reference;

    typedef typename std::add_const<T>::type const_value;
    typedef const_value* const_pointer;
    typedef const_value& const_reference;

    typedef std::shared_ptr<value_type> shared;
    typedef ndArray<T,N> self;



    // Constructors
    ndArray() { reset(); }
    ndArray( pointer ptr, const unsigned *size, bool manage ) { assign(ptr,size,manage); }


    // Copy constructor
    ndArray( const self& other ) { operator=(other); }
    self& operator= ( const self& other );

    // Check pointer validity
    inline bool empty() const { return !((bool) m_data); }
    inline operator bool() const { return m_data; }

    // Print array dimensions
    void info() const;



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // Clear contents
    void clear();
    void reset();


    // Assign a pointer or another instance
    void assign( pointer ptr, const unsigned *size, bool manage );
    void assign( const self& other ) { operator=(other); }


    // Swap contents with another array
    void swap( self& other );


    // Copy from another array
    template <typename U>
    void copy( const ndArray<U,N>& other );



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // 1D access
    inline reference operator[] ( unsigned n ) const 
        { return data()[ ND_ARRAY_PROTECT(n,m_numel) ]; }

    // ND access
    reference operator() ( const unsigned *subs ) const
        { return data()[ sub2ind<N>(subs, m_size, m_strides) ]; }

    reference operator() ( std::initializer_list<unsigned> subs ) const
        {
#ifdef ND_ARRAY_SAFE_ACCESS
            if ( subs.size() != N ) 
                throw std::length_error("Invalid coordinates length.");
#endif
            return data()[ sub2ind<N>(subs.begin(), m_size, m_strides) ];
        }

    // Coordinates access
    reference operator() ( unsigned i, ... ) const
        { 
            va_list vl; va_start(vl,i); 
            return data()[ i+sub2ind<N>(vl, m_size, m_strides) ]; 
        }


    // Access data directly
    inline const_pointer cdata() const { return m_data.get(); }
    inline pointer data() const { return m_data.get(); }

    // Iterators
    inline const_pointer cbegin() const { return data(); }
    inline const_pointer cend() const { return data() + m_numel; }

    inline pointer begin() const { return data(); }
    inline pointer end() const { return data() + m_numel; }



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // Dimensions
    inline const unsigned* size() const { return m_size; }
    inline unsigned size( unsigned n ) const { return m_size[ n % N ]; }
    inline const unsigned* strides() const { return m_strides; }
    inline unsigned stride( unsigned n ) const { return m_strides[ n % N ]; }
    inline unsigned numel() const { return m_numel; }
    inline unsigned ndims() const { return N; }



protected:

    void assign_shared( pointer ptr, bool manage );

    unsigned m_numel;
    unsigned m_size[N];
    unsigned m_strides[N];

    shared m_data;
};



        /********************     **********     ********************/
        /********************     **********     ********************/



// Include implementation
#include "ndArray.hpp"

#endif
```

`ndArray.hpp`

```
/**
 * Assignment operator.
 * Performs a shallow copy of the other instance.
 * For deep-copies, see copy() below.
 */
template <typename T, unsigned N>
ndArray<T,N>& ndArray<T,N>::operator=( const self& other )
{
    if ( other.m_data != m_data )
    {
        // Clear current instance first
        clear();

        // Copy data from other
        m_data  = other.m_data;
        m_numel = other.m_numel;
        std::copy_n( other.m_size, N, m_size );
        std::copy_n( other.m_strides, N, m_strides );
    }

    return *this;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Performs a deep-copy of another instance with possibly 
 * different value-type. Deep copies are allowed only if 
 * the pointer type is non-const (otherwise no assignment 
 * is possible). 
 *
 * To perform the copy, a new memory allocation is requested 
 * to store as many values as other.m_numel; the current 
 * instance takes ownership of this new memory. 
 * 
 * Note that subsequent shallow copies (see assignment operator)
 * will simply share this ownership (reference counting). 
 * Note also that this code might generate warnings because of
 * the value-cast performed on the values of other.
 */
template <typename T, unsigned N>
template <typename U>
void ndArray<T,N>::copy( const ndArray<U,N>& other )
{
    if ( !std::is_const<T>::value )
    {
        // Create new allocation only if necessary
        if ( other.numel() == m_numel )
        {
            // Otherwise simply copy dimensions
            std::copy_n( other.size(), N, m_size );
            std::copy_n( other.strides(), N, m_strides );
        }
        else
            assign( new T[ other.numel() ], other.size(), true );

        // Copy data
        auto dst = begin(); auto src = other.cbegin();
        for ( ;src != other.cend(); ++src, ++dst )  *dst = (T) *src;
    }
    else 
        throw std::logic_error("Const values cannot be assigned!");
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Reset shared pointer.
 * This will trigger the deletion of the underlying memory if
 * m_data is unique (m_data.use_count() == 1). Note that if the
 * data was assigned with 'manage' set to false (see below), 
 * the deleter(no_delete functor) will NOT release the memory.
 */
template <typename T, unsigned N>
void ndArray<T,N>::clear()
{
    m_data.reset();
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * More thorough cleanup. Calls clear() (see above), and sets 
 * all the rest to 0.
 */
template <typename T, unsigned N>
void ndArray<T,N>::reset()
{
    clear();
    m_numel = 0;
    std::fill_n( m_size, N, 0 );
    std::fill_n( m_strides, N, 0 );
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Swap contents with another ndArray.
 */
template <typename T, unsigned N>
void ndArray<T,N>::swap( self& other )
{
    std::swap( m_numel, other.m_numel );
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i )
    {
        std::swap( m_size[i], other.m_size[i] );
        std::swap( m_strides[i], other.m_strides[i] );
    }
    m_data.swap( other.m_data );
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Internal method (protected) to assign the shared pointer.
 * Dimensions are assumed to be taken care of by the public 
 * assign variants (see below); only the pointer, it's length
 * and the flag 'manage' are required here.
 *
 * 'manage' allows to specify whether or not the shared pointer 
 * should release the memory when the last refering instance is 
 * destroyed. 
 * 
 * If true, the default deleter std::default_delete will be 
 * assigned to the shared pointer. Note that this deleter releases 
 * memory allocated USING NEW ONLY; 
 *  DO NOT use malloc/calloc or other C allocation variants. 
 * 
 * If false, the deleter no_delete is given instead; this will NOT 
 * release the memory when the last refering instance is destroyed. 
 * Use only with either externally managed (eg Matlab) or static 
 * allocations.
 */
template <typename T, unsigned N>
void ndArray<T,N>::assign_shared( pointer ptr, bool manage )
{
    if (manage)
        m_data.reset( ptr );
    else
        m_data.reset( ptr, no_delete<T>() );
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Assign from pointer and size.
 *
 * If manage == true, the internal shared pointer m_data
 * will assume ownership of the memory pointed by ptr, and
 * try to release it using delete[] when the last refering 
 * instance gets destroyed. 
 * If ptr is dynamically allocated, make sure that the 
 * allocation is performed with NEW, and NOT C variants 
 * like malloc/calloc/etc.
 *
 * If manage == false, a dummy deleter (no_delete functor) is
 * passed to the shared pointer; nothing happens to the memory 
 * pointed by ptr when the last refering instance gets destroyed.
 */
template <typename T, unsigned N>
void ndArray<T,N>::assign( pointer ptr, const unsigned *size, bool manage )
{
    if ( ptr != data() )
    {
        // Compute internal dimensions
        m_numel = 1; 
        for ( unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i )
        {
            m_size[i] = size[i];
            m_numel  *= size[i];
            m_strides[ (i+1) % N ] = m_numel;
        }   m_strides[0] = 1;

        // Set data
        assign_shared( ptr, manage );
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Simply prints information about the dimensions of the 
 * n-dimensional array (size & number of elements).
 */
template <typename T, unsigned N>
void ndArray<T,N>::info() const
{
    if ( m_data )
    {
        printf("%u-dimensional array of size (%u", N, m_size[0]);
        for ( unsigned d = 1; d < N; ++d )
            printf(", %u", m_size[d]);
        printf(") = %u elements.\n", m_numel);
    }
    else
        printf("Empty %u-dimensional array.\n", N);
}
```